# Is it technically possible that a packet sent to through the loopback device (127.0.0.1) get lost?

Tags: sockets, tcp, loopback-address

I have a TCP client-server application implemented in C. The client and the server are two separate processes and the communication only happens using sockets which are bound to the loopback device (local address 127.0.0.1).

When the communication lasts for a long time (for example either the client or the server is sending many MB of data) I noticed that either the client or the server wait for a packet which never arrives and the timeout is reached. I tried to increase the timeout to 10000 (10 sec) but it didn't help.

I'm wondering why even for processes on the same computer a packet sent through the socket by either the client or the server can be lost.

Comment: Probably. Receive buffer full, for example

Comment: @user253751 This can be one option but in my case the `select` reaches a timeout which means that no data is available although the other end has instead sent some data which I suppose has been lost.

Comment: TCP doesn't lose data. TCP retransmits data if it is lost. Unless your timeout is really short (like 1 second) so it times out before retransmitting

Comment: So in other words you are saying that another thread or process has "stolen" the data from the socket. I don't see any other option.

Comment: My crystal ball says the right thread got all the data and is waiting for more even though it already got all of it. But that's just a crystal ball. It doesn't always make correct predictions.

Comment: My crystal ball says the same. It is a common error to assume that a single write on one side of the TCP connection matches exactly a single read on the other side. This assumption is wrong and might cause the behavior you see, i.e. that data seem to get lost even though they were actually read, only together with other data. But - no code here to point out a specific error.